# solve this with sql or php - performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with alot of rows looking something like this:

```
id-name-date---pcs
1 - x - 01-01 -10
2 - y - 01-01 -15
3 - z - 01-01 -8
4 - x - 02-01 -25
5 - y - 02-01 -10
6 - z - 02-01 -5
```

What I would like to do is a query that shows the development/difference of pcs for the names, between one month and antoher(in this case Feb and Jan), like this:

```
id-name-pcs
1 - x - (15)
2 - y - (-5)
3 - z - (-3)
```

Is it possible to do this with sql only or do I need to involve php?

Would it have an noticable impact on the server if I loop through all rows and did the calculation in php?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The parentheses is not suppose to be a part of the query results. Only for this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique I used is to Join the table's January portion with February portion and then find the difference.
See the query bellow (assuming `gsub` is your table name)

```
SELECT 
    g1.id, g1.name, g2.pcs-g1.pcs `pcs`
FROM 
    gsub AS g1
INNER JOIN
    gsub AS g2 
ON
    (g1.name=g2.name 
    AND 
    month(g1.`date`) = 1 
    AND 
    month(g2.`date`) = 2);
```

Result

```
+----+------+------+
| id | name | pcs  |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | x    |   15 |
|  2 | y    |   -5 |
|  3 | z    |   -3 |
+----+------+------+
```

Comment: Hmm can't get this to work. I see the logic but it returns 0 rows.
I changed it to  LIKE "2012-02%" and 01% (my format is yyyy-mm-dd) but still no success. And I do have two of the same names added in the two months.

Comment: @Josef What is the format of your `date` column? is `date` type too?

Comment: It's a timestamp, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss but should'nt LIKE "2012-02%" to the trick for that format? I use it for grouping and stuff and that works great

Comment: I believe you can't use LIKE for dates as if they were strings.

Comment: Hm ok. I will make it a date and try again. Thanks!

Comment: @Josef timestamp and datetime are same. Dont change it. If you want to group by Month and year use `GROUP BY YEAR(\`date\`)+'-'+MONTH(\`date\`)`

Comment: I get the grouping part to work with timestamp, no problem there. But I don't get the above answer to work with either LIKE "2012-02%" and ="2012-02%" instead of the month(mydate) = 2.

Comment: And month(g2.`date`) = 2) returns zero rows, just as LIKE date%

Comment: I tried this in MS Access and that worked, with a date format. So I will try it when I get home.

Comment: Worked like a charm now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do a `JOIN` of the table with itself, like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.pcs AS 'pcs at 01-01', t2.pcs AS 'pcs at 02-02', t1.pcs - t2.pcs AS diff
FROM table t1 
JOIN table t2 ON (t1.name = t2.name AND t2.date = '02-01') 
WHERE t1.date = '01-01';
```

Note that `t1` and `t2` are different aliases for the same table.

Also: **table** needs to be substituted by your specific database table name, and the **dates** need to be in a valid format ('01-01' and '02-01' won't work - use the full date format of your column type).

---

For more complex stuff, I usually do one or two database queries, and perform the calculations in the PHP side. I have once transformed a big query which took one minute to run, into a couple of queries mixed with PHP loop, which ran almost instantly.

But, in your case, the goal can be achieved by a simple SQL query, which will not prejudice performance at all.

Comment: Thanks, but same here, returns 0 rows. And yes, thats why I asked, this will will be a more complex query in the end.

Comment: It should work. Have you changed `date = '01-01'` to a valid date, and all other parts of the query which needs change to your specific needs (the table name, etc.)?

Comment: @Josef: oh, sorry - I just corrected the query. The `ON` condition of the `JOIN` couldn't be `t1.id = t2.id` (it would never match different dates and same IDs) - it must compare the common field: `t1.name = t2.name`, in this case.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if that could be the issue. I'll do another try later today. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

the way you are asking, I shouldn't even answer (In the future, show us, what you have tried). If you haven't tried anything, start out with something like this:

```
select name, sum(pcs) from mytable where cast(substring(date,0,2),UNSIGNED)<2 group by name order by sum(pcs)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realised that my formulation was bad formulated. I havn't tried anything yet because I am not sure how to begin. And also, my question was regarding the performance. I know how to this with the help of php and that would be the easiest solution for me. But maybe not the best. I will try to work with your answer.

Comment: after re-reading your question, i think you better go with one of the approaches above. my thing was just adding the quantities, which is not what you wanted.